# iTextSharp removeUsageRights stopped working

Tags: itext

I've been using the code sample from iText in Action (8.7.2)  to deal with the "cannot save" issue with PDF forms and iTextSharp. It was working fine, but recently the fix stopped working and all the variations of the code listed in the book to prevent the saving problem haven't solved it.

I'm using the latest version of the iTextSharp library. Has anyone else run into this? Did an Acrobat update break it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

works for me using iTextSharp 5.0.6, Reader X,  and [Listing 8.29 ReaderEnabledForm](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter08&ex=ReaderEnabledForm) from the book. (it's the file named 'xfa_preserved.pdf' in the zip download)

IIRC the last couple of times i saw similar on [the mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/itext-questions), the problem was specific to how the original PDF was created. if you subscribe, you can post the original PDF and hopefully one of the experts can take a look if they have time.

Comment: Yes, that's the code that I'm using. I've just subscribed to the list and I'll look the archive over. If that doesn't help I'll post the original form and see what comes up.

Comment: Mailing list helped me sort it out. I was writing a watermark to the PDF after filling the fields and the reader extension wasn't enabled in the original document.

Comment: i saw your posts there. glad to see you got everything working. the development team takes potential bugs seriously, so problems like these are almost always worked out :)